# Python: Sort dictionary by value (equal values)

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, python-3.6

I have this dictionary and I want to sort it by values.

```
d = {3: '__init__', 5: 'other', 7: 'hey', 11: 'hey'}
```

Expected output:

```
{3:'__init__', 7: 'hey', 11: 'hey' 5: 'other'}
```

I wrote this function

```
def ordenar(dic):
            d = {}
            list_2 = list(dic.values())
            list_1 = list(dic.keys())
            list_3 = []
            for i,j in zip(list_1,list_2):
                list_3.append((i,j))
            def quicksort(l):
              if len(l) <= 1:
                  return l
              else:
                  (less_eq, piv, greater) = partition(l)
                  less_eq = quicksort(less_eq)
                  greater = quicksort(greater)
              return less_eq + [piv] + greater

            def partition(l):
                 piv = l[0]
                 i = 1
                 less_eq = []
                 greater = []
                 while i < len(l):
                     current = l[i]
                     if current <= piv:
                         less_eq.append(current)
                     else:
                         greater.append(current)
                     i = i + 1
                 return (less_eq, piv, greater)
            s = quicksort(list_3)

            for i in s:

                d[i[0]] = i[1]
            return d
```

Output obtained:

```
{3: '__init__', 5: 'other', 7: 'hey', 11: 'hey'}
```

How can I fixed it witouth modules? Can you help me please?

**Edit:**

I want to order the dictionary by values. If the values are equal what I want is that values sort by it keys. Is it posible?

Comment: lexographically `'hey'` comes before `'hey   '` ... also you should mention in your question you cant use sorted ... as using sorted is the right way to solve this

Comment: You’re comparing `current <= piv`. Try printing `current` and `piv`. Are they what you expect?

Comment: @Ryan I want to order the dictionary by values. If the values are equal what I want is that values sort by it keys. Is it posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dictionaries are unordered (well pre 3.6 at least), instead sort the items

```
d = {3: '__init__', 5: 'other', 7: 'hey  ', 11: 'hey'}
print(sorted(d.items(),key=lambda item:(item[0].strip(),item[1])))

# output => [(3, '__init__'), (7, 'hey  '), (11, 'hey'), (5, 'other')]
```

if you really want it as a dict (for reasons i cant fathom) and you are using 3.6+ then you can just  create a new dict from your sorted items

```
d2 = dict(sorted(d.items(),key=lambda item:item[1]))
```

*(note that in 3.6 that dicts maintain order is an implementation detail, not a guarantee, but 3.7+ its part of the language specification)

you can do the same thing in earlier pythons using collections.OrderedDict

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d2 = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(),key=lambda item:item[1]))
```

since you cant use builtin sorted here is a bubble sort for you ... although I dont understand how having strangers on the internet write a sort function for you is any better than just using the python builtin sorted

```
def my_bubble_sort(list_thing,key_fn):
    # sort a list in place by a key fn
    changed = True
    while changed:
        changed = False
        for i in range(len(list_thing)-1):
            if key_fn(list_thing[i]) > key_fn(list_thing[i+1]):
               list_thing[i],list_thing[i+1] = list_thing[i+1],list_thing[i]
               changed = True

d = {3: '__init__', 5: 'other', 7: 'hey  ', 11: 'hey'}
d_list = d.items()
my_bubble_sort(d_list,lambda item:(item[1].strip(),item[0]))
print(d_list)
```

Comment: It does not matter if the output is a list or a dictionary, what matters is the order, in your output it appears   (11, 'hey) before   (7,' hey ')and I want (7,' hey ') before  (11, 'hey)

Comment: `'hey'` is lexographically less than `'hey   '` so you will need to elaborate on the rule that makes `'hey   '` less than `'hey'` in order for me to tell you how to implement it

Comment: I made an assumtion that you want to strip the empty spaces off the values before comparison and then with the clarification you wanted the key to be the secondary sort i figured out what your rule was

Comment: I am sorry I made some mistakes writting the question. So is posible do what I am looking for? Without sorted or collections?

Comment: I saw it but is there another way without sorted or collections?